# Why overwriting an object argument does not pass the new reference to outside scope?

Tags: lua

I'm a bit confused with how Lua treats object references in function arguments. Consider this example:

```
local tableA = {name = "A"}
local tableB = {name = "B"}
local tableC = {name = "C"}

local function childA(a, b)
    a = tableC
    b.name = "This works"
end

local function childB(a, b)
    print("a =", a.name) -- expected to print "C"
    print("b =", b.name) -- prints "This works" as expected
end

local function parentFunction(a, b)
    childA(a, b)
    childB(a, b)
end

parentFunction(tableA, tableB)
```

I would expect that in the `childA` function the `a` parameter will be replaced by reference to `tableC` that will continue to be `tableC` from now on, but it does not happen. Whereas if I change just a property of such parameter in the `b` parameter it will affect reads of the object down the line. Why the overwrite is not working like this?

Comment: Why would you expect that to happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table values are copied by reference, not by value.

in `childA` you assign `tableC` to `a`. `a` is local to `childA`.

`a` = `tableC` just adds a second reference to the table `tableC` refers to.
This has no effect on the actual table nor any other reference to it.

Once `childA` has returned, `a` is out of scope so the reference you just added is removed.

Make sure you understand that in `local tableA = {name = "A"}` you create a table value with the table construtor `{}` and a local reference `tableA` to that table value. `local a = tableA` just creates another reference to that table, not a second table! Then `a = tableC` re-refers `a` to the table created here `local tableC = {name = "C"}`

You basically write another address on a piece of paper. That doesn't affect the house at the original address.